# NPM not installing on local machine

Tags: vue.js, npm-install

Below are the specifications.

```
Node Version : v16.13.0
Npm Version : 8.1.2
```

Below are the commands that i tried one by one.

```
npm cache clean

npm install --no-bin-links

npm install --save
```

After that, I got the below error. As clearly shown in the error that the `paython PATH` issue then I tried the below command and the cmd is halted from last 16 hours

[image: Error Screenshot]

After installing the windows build tools it's stuck the screen for the last 16 hours. Below is the command that i execute.

> npm install --global windows-build-tools

[image]

I tried all possibilities like removing `node_modules` dir and removing `package.json`, `package-lock.json`

Answer (score 0):

From the error it looks like you have python 3 installed, but the print statement of a module you're trying to compile with node-gyp is written the python 2 way (that is, it's an actual statement and not a function). Try to install python 2 and put it in the path as "python2" like the error message says.